# Open a port in firewall with Java?

Tags: java, cmd, firewall

Is there any way to open a port with java socket in the firewall.

Maybe someone have an idea with cmd command line or with another way please.

Comment: Which firewall are you referring to? Windows firewall? Software or Hardware and if so what brand etc. Much more information is needed for anyone to be able to look at this.

Comment: Just in windows firewall, thats all, my objectif is to use No-IP with that port, to send somme commands to that machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using CMD

If you want to open a port on windows Vista and higher then you can use the following command

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="My_Rule_Name_Incoming" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=4000
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="My_Rule_Name_Outgoing" dir=out action=allow protocol=TCP localport=4000
```

Note that you will have to run that command on the PC in question